# Barcode Generation (Code 39) MPDF

Tags: php, barcode, mpdf, code39

I'm able to generate a barcode by using the following code:

```
    $code = '12345';
```

Then to generate the barcode, I do the following:

```
   <barcode code="$code" type="C39" size="0.5" height="2.0" />
```

However, it is not generating the correct id. Is there something that I'm doing wrong? What I'm using is the mPDF tool, and I can't change to a different pdf tool.

Thank you..

Comment: I don't really understand the question. What exactly isn't going right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell what syntax the two code snippets are in, but if that PHP variable needs to be printed in XML you need to specify that it is PHP:

```
<barcode code="<?php echo $code; ?>" type="C39" size="0.5" height="2.0" />
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you..

Comment: Awesome, Glad to help!